# C# Task async верно ли я его использую?

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода, async-await, task

У меня есть 5 операций, которые должны выполняться одновременно.
Я пробую использовать Task async. 
Я сделал такой тестовый пример. Результат меня устраивает, но правильно ли я использую эту технологию?

Код:

```
class SomeClass
    {

        /*
         * Task1 - Работа с балансами
         * Task2 - Работа с статусами
         * Task3 - Проверка на неотправленые сообщения
         * Task4 - Отправка ежемесячных затрат по Клиентам
         * Task5 - Обработка массовой рассылки
         */

        List<Task> listTasks;
        List<object> testObjects;

        public SomeClass()
        {
            testObjects = new List<object>();
            listTasks = new List<Task>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
                testObjects.Add((object)i);
        }

        async Task Balances()
        {
            await GetBalancesTask();
        }

        async Task Statuses()
        {
            await GetStatusesTask();
        }

        async Task NonSendMessages()
        {
            await GetNonSendMessagesTask();
        }

        async Task ClientCosts()
        {
            await GetClientCostsTask();
        }

        async Task Bulks()
        {
            await GetBulksTask();
        }

        #region Работа с балансами

        Task GetBalancesTask()
        {
            Task T = new Task(GetBalances);
            listTasks.Add(T);
            return T;
        }

        void GetBalances()
        {
            //получение балансов
            foreach (var obj in testObjects)
                Console.WriteLine( "__balance_" + obj.ToString());
        }

        #endregion

        #region Работа с статусами

        Task GetStatusesTask()
        {
            Task T = new Task(GetStatuses);
            listTasks.Add(T);
            return T;
        }

        void GetStatuses()
        {
            //Работа с статусами
            foreach (var obj in testObjects)
                Console.WriteLine("__status_" + obj.ToString());
        }

        #endregion

        #region Проверка на неотправленые сообщения

        Task GetNonSendMessagesTask()
        {
            Task T = new Task(GetNonSendMessages);
            listTasks.Add(T);
            return T;
        }

        void GetNonSendMessages()
        {
            //Проверка на неотправленые сообщения
            foreach (var obj in testObjects)
                Console.WriteLine("__nonsendMessages_" + obj.ToString());
        }

        #endregion

        #region Отправка ежемесячных затрат по Клиентам

        Task GetClientCostsTask()
        {
            Task T = new Task(GetClientCosts);
            listTasks.Add(T);
            return T;
        }

        void GetClientCosts()
        {
            //Отправка ежемесячных затрат по Клиентам
            foreach (var obj in testObjects)
                Console.WriteLine("__costs_" + obj.ToString());
        }

        #endregion

        #region Обработка массовой рассылки

        Task GetBulksTask()
        {
            Task T = new Task(GetBulks);
            listTasks.Add(T);
            return T;
        }

        void GetBulks()
        {
            //Обработка массовой рассылки
            foreach (var obj in testObjects)
                Console.WriteLine("__bulks_" + obj.ToString());
        }

        #endregion

        public void StartAll()
        {
            Balances();
            Statuses();
            NonSendMessages();
            ClientCosts();
            Bulks();

            foreach (var task in listTasks)
            {
                task.Start();
            }

            Task.WaitAll(listTasks.ToArray());
        }
    }
```

Возможно что-то здесь можно упростить?

Comment: Слишком много однотипного кода. Сделайте общий базовый класс.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
>     async Task Balances()
>     {
>         await GetBalancesTask();
>     }
> ```

Лишний метод. Его надо убрать, а `GetBalancesTask` переименовать в `Balances`.

> ```
>     Task GetBalancesTask()
>     {
>         Task T = new Task(GetBalances);
>         listTasks.Add(T);
>         return T;
>     }
> ```

Вы кладете задачу в список только для того чтобы почти сразу же ее запустить. Почему не запустить ее сразу же? Используйте `Task.Run` и забудьте про список задач вообще.

> ```
>     void GetBalances()
>     {
>         //получение балансов
>         foreach (var obj in testObjects)
>             Console.WriteLine( "__balance_" + obj.ToString());
>     }
> ```

Метод ничего не делает кроме того что ведет логи. Добавьте хотя бы `Thread.Sleep` для имитации деятельности.

Кроме того, тут не ясно, какого рода задача планируется - вычислительная, сетевой запрос или файловый ввод-вывод. Для последних двух синхронное исполнение в отдельном потоке считается не лучшим вариантом.

> ```
>     public void StartAll()
>     {
>         Balances();
>         Statuses();
>         NonSendMessages();
>         ClientCosts();
>         Bulks();
>
>         // ...
>
>         Task.WaitAll(listTasks.ToArray());
>     }
> ```

Вызываемые методы возвращают задачи - но далее они нигде не используются, последняя строчка ждет завершения задач из какого-то левого списка. Это - нарушение абстракции, которую дают вызываемые методы, "прыжок через слой".

Правильнее будет собрать возвращаемые значения и дождаться их:

```
    public void StartAll()
    {
        var b = Balances();
        var s = Statuses();
        var nsm = NonSendMessages();
        var cc = ClientCosts();
        var bu = Bulks();

        // ...

        Task.WaitAll(b, s, nsm, cc, bu);
    }
```

Кстати, почему метод, который называется **Start**All - вдруг ждет окончания задач?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Ждать окончания в принципе не нужно.  Может ли быть такое, что какая-то задача не завершится и будет висеть бесконечно?

Comment: @LeonardBertone да, может быть. К примеру, если вы ее забудете запустить. Или если внутри - бесконечный цикл.

Comment: спасибо большое. Т.е. получается, что с Task не обязательно async/await использовать?

Comment: @LeonardBertone странный вывод

Comment: получается что Task - уже означает асинхронную операцию.
а с async/await можно любую операцию сделать асинхронной?

Comment: @LeonardBertone нет. Любую операцию можно сделать "асинхронной" (именно так, в кавычках) через Task.Run. async/await используется для комбинирования асинхронных операций.

Comment: @LeonardBertone первая же часть  - верная. Тип данных Task означает асинхронную операцию.